# How to set payload as constructor-arg value in service-activator

Tags: spring-integration

I've started with SI and kind of stuck right now as we want to use SI in one of our existing project avoiding changes where we can.

A bean which we would be using as a service activator accepts an constructor argument of a java object.

that object is in the payload but then I'm unable to set it using inner bean usage of service-activator

```
<service-activator input-channel="ADMIN_TEST_CONNECTION" method="testConnection">
  <beans:bean class="mypackage.request.AdminRequestProcessor">
                <beans:constructor-arg value="payload"/>
            </beans:bean>
 </service-activator>
```

it's complaining about Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type.

Please help in how to access payload and set it as an constructor argument.

If I go via non- constructor arg route and change existing java object then it works with this call in the service activator

expression="@bean.testConnection(payload)"/>

but I don't wish you to change the existing java code until there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have choice unless change something or add code around existing.

Service-Activator performs its functionality against each incoming message in the `input-channel`. And that functionality is exactly method invocation where `Message` is used as a context for method arguments.

Not sure what you are going to do with that payload, but that doesn't look correct to use statefull object like your `AdminRequestProcessor`. Just don't forget that you may have many incoming message, but service-activator should be consistent.

Plus don't forget that `<beans:bean>` is `singleton`, so your `AdminRequestProcessor` is instantiated only once.

Looking to your sample I'd suggest something like this:

```
expression="new AdminRequestProcessor(payload).testConnection()"/>
```

If you really don't want to change anything in your code.

Everything rest you can find in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator-namespace).

Comment: Hello Artem, is it possible to use the service activator class name dynamically, like in my case it would be easy and single config If I can say              expression="'new'+  payload.type+'Processor'(payload).testConnection()"/>

Comment: M-m-m. Sorry, your question isn't clear. What does that `use class dynamically` means? It recalls me resent question like "how to cast at runtime?" Maybe a new SO thread with proper info and config/test-case to play from my side locally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171203/how-to-name-and-initialize-a-class-of-a-service-activator-dynamically