# How to name and initialize a class of a service activator dynamically

Tags: spring-integration

This is follow-up on my earlier question [How to set payload as constructor-arg value in service-activator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044107/how-to-set-payload-as-constructor-arg-value-in-service-activator).

We've 12 different classes like AProcessor, Bprocessor and so on.. and the each constructor accept common payload and execute same declared method in them 'publish'.

Now, I was thinking to have single common channel and service activator in SI which can handle this but then how can I put the class name in the expression dynamically which I can derive from the payload.type.

I was trying something like below but its not working

> <service-activator input-channel="COMMON_PUBLISH_CHANNEL"               expression="'new mypackage.'+payload.type+  'RequestProcessor'(payload.myservice).publish(payload.data)">
>   </service-activator>

I want to save from writing 12 channels and service activators if I can do at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggests to move such a logic into Java class and still have one `<service-activator>`. All the hard work to decide which target processor to invoke should be done there, in the service-method.

Spring Integration with its power to be so flexible with all those components and channels between them may lead to the misleading that it is programming language. When the real language is Java and we shouldn't forget its generic functionality.

Although we can achieve your wishes with Spring Integration anyway using SpEL magic:

```
<chain>
   <header-enricher name="service" expression="@serviceRegistry[payload.type]"/>
   <service-activator expression="headers[service].process(payload)"/>
<chain>
```

Comment: I've not used the serviceRegistry before, can you please point me to the relevant resources for it so that I can put the right bean for it etc?  thanks

Comment: There is no such one. That was just hypothetical code. You should write your own one if that. And, yes, you won't be able to bypass Java there :-)

Comment: Yes, did the work in a java bean class and it's working.